# AutoMapper: Prevent Shallow Copy of Self-Mappings

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

I'm using AutoMapper (version 11.0.1) in a .NET 6 application, and one of its features seems to be that if you map a type to itself, it'll let you do that out of the box.

```
IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(/* add profiles here */).CreateMapper();

Foo oldFoo = new Foo();
Foo myFoo = mapper.Map<Foo>(oldFoo); // Doesn't throw an exception.
```

The problem is that `myFoo` and `oldFoo` are the same reference/object. A new instance is *not* created! (You can verify this by using `ReferenceEquals`. It's doing a shallow copy.) You can mitigate this by adding a self-mapping to your AutoMapper profile.

```
public class MyProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    CreateMap<Foo, Foo>(); // Now calls to Map() will return a new instance.
}
```

My question: Is there a way to *disable* the behavior of "map non-specified self-mappings"? I would much rather AutoMapper throw the usual "no configurations found" exception and be explicit. There are some scenarios where I do *not* want to edit the new object, and therefore also edit the old object by side effect.

Comment: Based on [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/656) issue there is no build in way to achieve this.

Comment: Seems you're right. Suppose a way to achieve this would be to fork the project and remove `AssignableMapper`, although I'm not sure what other internal implications that would have. (Probably would bust up most property mappings for example, when mapping anything really.)

Comment: Another workaround can be building "reasonable" set of mappings using reflection.